# How to Post Data Form to mongoDB with ReactJS using hooks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-hooks

*Hi everyone, I am facing an issue while trying to post data to my mongoDB from the frontend using React Hooks. The problem is that when I send the data instead of getting the all body I am only getting the id as response in my database. I don't know what I am missing in my code, I really need your help and I am open for all advices so I can better understand how to do. Here bellow are my codes:*

[image]

**CustomerPost:**

```
        import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function CreateCustomer() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [passport, setPassport] = useState("");
  const [booked, setBooked] = useState(false);

  const onChangeName = (e) => {
    setName({ name: e.target.value });
  };
  const onChangeEmail = (e) => {
    setEmail({ email: e.target.value });
  };
  const onChangePhone = (e) => {
    setPhone({ phone: e.target.value });
  };
  const onChangePassport = (e) => {
    setPassport({ passport: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const bookingData = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
      passport: passport,
    };
    console.log(bookingData);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/customers", bookingData)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setName(name);
        setEmail(email);
        setPhone(phone);
        setPassport(passport);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    setBooked(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {booked ? (
        <p className="bookedMsg">Your room was booked successfully!!!</p>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="form contact-form">
          <div className="input-group-wrap">
            <div className="input-group">
              <input
                className="input"
                type="text"
                onChange={onChangeName}
                placeholder="Name..."
                required
              />
              <span className="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input
                className="input"
                type="email"
                onChange={onChangeEmail}
                placeholder="Email..."
                required
              />
              <span className="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input
                onChange={onChangePhone}
                type="number"
                className="input"
                placeholder="Phone..."
                required
              />
              <span className="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input
                onChange={onChangePassport}
                type="number"
                className="input"
                placeholder="Passport..."
                required
              />
              <span className="bar"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn form-btn btn-purple">
            BOOK NOW
            <span className="dots">
              <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
            </span>
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Customer.Route.js:**

```
     const Express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
const router = Express.Router();
const Controller = require("./Controller");

const data = require("./controller");

router.post("/", cors(), function (req, res) {
  Controller.insertCustomer(req.body)
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(data.status).send({ message: data });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      res.status(data.status).send({ message: err.message });
    });
});

router.get("/", cors(), function (req, res) {
  Controller.searchAll()
    .then((data) => {
      res.status(data.status).send({ data: data.message });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(err.status).send({ message: err.message });
    });
});

router.get("/:id", cors(), function (req, res) {
  Controller.search(req.params.id)
    .then((data) => {
      res.status(data.status).send({ message: data.message });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(err.status).send({ message: err.message });
    });
});

router.put("/:id", cors(), function (req, res) {
  Controller.updateCustomer(req.params.id, req.body)
    .then((data) => {
      res.status(data.status).send({ message: data.message });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(err.status).send({ message: err.message });
    });
});

router.delete("/:id", cors(), (req, res) => {
  Controller.delete(req.params.id)
    .then((data) => {
      res.status(data.status).send({ message: data.message });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(err.status).send({ message: err.message });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**dbConfig:**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const CustomerSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    require: false,
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
  },
  passport: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
  },
});

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Connected to the mongodb");
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Customer", CustomerSchema);
```

**Controller.js:**

```
const mongoose = require("../dbSchema/dbConfig");

const CustomerSchema = mongoose.model("Customer");

const Controller = function () {
  this.insertCustomer = function (data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var Customer = new CustomerSchema({
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        phone: data.phone,
        passport: data.passport,
      });
      Customer.save()
        .then(function () {
          resolve({ status: 200, message: "Customer inserted Successfully" });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          reject({ status: 500, message: "Error " + err });
        });
    });
  };

  this.updateCustomer = function (id, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      CustomerSchema.update({ _id: id }, data)
        .then(() => {
          resolve({ status: 200, message: "Customer updated Successfully" });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          reject({ status: 500, message: err });
        });
    });
  };

  this.searchAll = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      CustomerSchema.find()
        .exec()
        .then(function (data) {
          resolve({ status: 200, message: data });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          reject({ status: 500, message: err });
        });
    });
  };

  this.search = function (id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      CustomerSchema.find({ _id: id })
        .exec()
        .then(function (Customer) {
          resolve({ status: 200, message: Customer });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject({ status: 500, message: err });
        });
    });
  };

  this.delete = function (id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      CustomerSchema.remove({ _id: id })
        .then(() => {
          resolve({ status: 200, message: "Customer Removed" });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject({ status: 500, message: err });
        });
    });
  };
};
module.exports = new Controller();
```

**Route.js:**

```
const Express = require("express");
const Routes = Express.Router();
const CustomerRoute = require("../CustomerController/Customer.Route");
Routes.use("/customers", CustomerRoute);
module.exports = Routes;
```

Comment: Can you please include the code in your controller and your models? Have you used Postman yet to test your backend routes? Is the data being saved in the database? And you are receiving the id back? We need a little more specific information

Comment: Hi @Alex Yepes, thanks for your feedback I have just add the files you ask. But I have used postman everything is working well, I have try also with insomnia it worked, only in the frontend with the form is not working and I don't know what I am missing. I really need help here thanks.

Comment: So you said it works with postman, but when you make the call from react what is exactly happening? Is the data being saved correctly? Or are you getting any error?

Comment: In that console.log after making the axios call, what are you getting back?

Comment: There is no error at all when making the call from react, I am only getting the id in mongodb after the call from react instead of getting the entire body. After the call I am getting the success message as it suppose to give me, I don't know what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending an empty object from react, can you try adding async and await to your onSubmit function. I'm posting it as an answer to have more space for the code.

```
const onSubmit = async (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    const bookingData = { 
        name: name, 
        email: email, 
        phone: phone, 
        passport: passport, 
    }; 
    console.log(bookingData); 

    await axios.post("/customers", 
    bookingData).then((res) => { 
    console.log(res.data); 
    setName(name);
    setEmail(email); 
    setPhone(phone); 
    setPassport(passport); 
    }).catch((error) => { 
    console.log(error); }); 
    setBooked(true); 
};
```

Comment: Hey Alex Yepes, thanks for your assistance but it gave me the some result as before. I got only the id, the rest are not coming sending for some reason

Comment: When you console.log(bookingData) are you seeing the whole object in the console?

Comment: I have edit the question and added the screen shoot of  what I am getting in the console.

Comment: Inside your controller, can you change your insertCustomer method for the following: ``this.insertCustomer = function (data) { return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { CustomerSchema.save(data).then(function () { resolve({ status: 200, message: "Customer inserted Successfully" }); }) .catch(function (err) { reject({ status: 500, message: "Error " + err }); }); }); };``

Comment: I have try this : this.insertCustomer = function (data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      CustomerSchema.save(data)
        .then(function () {
          resolve({ status: 200, message: "Customer inserted Successfully" });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          reject({ status: 500, message: "Error " + err });
        });
    });
  };

Comment: and this : this.insertCustomer = function (data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      CustomerSchema.save({ name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        phone: data.phone,
        passport: data.passport,})
        .then(function () {
          resolve({ status: 200, message: "Customer inserted Successfully" });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          reject({ status: 500, message: "Error " + err });
        });
    });
  }; in both case I am getting error. I am not able to post data.

Comment: I think the issue comes from the controller itself. Do you have this repo somewhere so I can take a closer look at the whole thing and reproduce the errors? I'm not in the office until tomorrow morning, so in the meantime try to play with the code in your controller to see if you can find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify your handleChange functions, something like this:

```
const onChangeName = (e) => {
   setName(e.target.value)
 }
```

I hope this works for you